# I am working on Flutter with IOT. Stuck with connection to a device with wifi and send the credentials to the device

Tags: flutter, iot, android-wifi, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

My question was is their any way to connect the ESP32 with wifi connection and send our password to that selected device to connect that device to wifi of the same network our **flutter** **app** was connected to.The password also should send by the flutter application.
thank you so much in advance.Please help me na.